# mozilla pdf.js without fullview

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf-generation

I liked this pdf viewer https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ Demo: http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html I want to open this in a div (say 400px width) How can I do that? Right now I am seeing only full view of this viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is with a iframe, if it is what you mean.
You want to see that page inserted on your page?

If its, use  and set the size and scroolbars properties to see it on the size that you want, there is the property src i think where you can put the url.